# Find specific Cell and using it to create a range

Tags: vba, excel

I am currently searching an excel sheet to find a specific cell:

```
Set findCell = ActiveSheet.Range("D:D").Find(What:=startTerm).Offset(1, 0)
```

Once I have this cell I want to create a range from that cell downwards an arbitrary number, it doesn't matter now.

```
Set instrumentList = ActiveSheet.Range("findCell:D100").Cells
```

I cant' seem to figure out the syntax to make this correct. I essentialy just need to find the cell with some specific text and create a range downwards from it, but I just get an application error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You would want to use `Offset()` again like this: (added check for `startTerm` not found)

```
If Not findCell is Nothing Then
    Set instrumentList = ActiveSheet.Range(findCell, findCell.Offset(x, 0))
Else
    MsgBox startTerm & " Not Found!"
    Exit Sub
End If
```

Where `x` is your arbitrary number of rows down you want to go.

Comment: May want to check that `findCell` is not nothing first.

Comment: @JasonFaulkner Happy Now? :-D

Comment: Thanks; very simple solution!